# How do I make 400k requests 200 at a time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks, axios, out-of-memory

I have a massive amount of requests and I need to run more or less 200 to 600 of said requests simultaneously, but no more than that amount. At the moment I'm sending the 400k requests simultaneously but that chews my heap memory, and then jumps on it - that is to say that it uses multiple gigabytes of memory, which I don't have.

I'm currently using a loop similar to this to handle the requests:

```
["url1", "url2", ...].forEach(async item => {
    Axios(config)
        .then(res => DO STUFF)
        .catch(err => console.log(err);
    await DO_MORE STUFF
});
```

The links are actually stored in a MongoDB collection, I'm using Cursor.forEach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `nextObject` function of cursor.

Here is a solution using it (untested, there might be syntax mistake)

```
let axiosConfigs = [];
async function runAxios() {
  // Do your axios stuff here on axiosConfigs
  // Here is an example :
  await Promise.all(axiosConfigs.map((config) => {
    return Axios(config);
  }))
  // Once finished, clear the axiosConfigs array      
  axiosConfigs = [];
}

function createAxiosConfig(urlRecord) {
 // return here the axios config for this url record        
}

const cursor = db.collection("urls").find({});

while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const urlRecord= await cursor.next();
  axiosConfigs.push(createAxiosConfig(urlRecord));
  if(axiosConfigs.length === 200) {
    await runAllAxioses()
  }
}
```

with this you will have batches of 200 axios requests. And start to build the next batch once all the 200 axios queries are over

Answer (score 1):

So you have to slice your array into smaller arrays and loop for each slice with ramp up timeout.

```
 let urls = ["url1", "url2", ...];
 let reqPerTime = 400; 
 let rampUp = 0 ; 

function loopRecursively (from ) {
   if ( from > urls.length ) { return ;} 

  let arr = urls.slice(from,  from + reqPerTime ); 
  arr.forEach(async item => {
    Axios(config)
     .then(res => DO STUFF)
     .catch(err => console.log(err);
     await DO_MORE STUFF
    });
   rampUp = rampUp + 500; 
   setTimeout ( () => { loopRecursively( from + reqPerTime ) }, rampUp );
  }

  loopRecursively(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

In async function, you need to use await for stop loop until operation performed.
you alerady did but loop also return array of promise which you need to resolve to get right result

```
const urls = ["url1", "url2", ...]
const allPromise = urls.map(async item => {
    try {
    const res =  await Axios(config)
    await DO_MORE STUFF
    } catch(error) {
        console.log({ error })
    }
});
await Promise.all(allPromise)
```

If outer function is not async function then you can use `.then`